# Kotlin Dagger Hilt missing binding

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

How do I fix this binding issue:
C:\Users\win 10\Desktop\5. code-app\app\build\generated\hilt\component_sources\benchmark\com\Application_HiltComponents.java:137: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.StoryApi cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements Application_GeneratedInjector,
^
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.StoryApi is injected at
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.StoryService(storyApi)
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.StoryService is injected at
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.StoryRepository(storyService)
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.StoryRepository is injected at
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.GetStoryUseCase(storyRepository)
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.model.GetStoryUseCase is injected at
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.viewmodel.HomeViewModel(getStoryUseCase)
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.viewmodel.HomeViewModel is injected at
com.usecases.offline_new_stories_added.viewmodel.HomeViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
@dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [comApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.Application_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.Application_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]

```
class GetStoryUseCase @Inject constructor(private val storyRepository: StoryRepository){
    suspend operator fun invoke(): List<StoryItem> {
        return storyRepository.getStories()
    }
}
```

module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RetrofitStoryModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("Story")
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL_WP)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("StoryAPI")
    fun provideStoryApi(@Named("Story")retrofit: Retrofit): StoryApi {
        return  retrofit.create(StoryApi::class.java )
    }
}
```

interface

```
interface StoryApi {

    @GET("posts")
    suspend fun getStories(): Response<List<StoryModel>>
}
```

Repository

```
@Singleton
class StoryRepository @Inject constructor(private val storyService: StoryService){

    suspend fun getStories(): List<StoryItem> {
        return storyService.getStories().map {
            it.toStoryItem()
        }
    }

}
```

service

```
class StoryService @Inject constructor(private val storyApi: StoryApi){
    suspend fun getStories(): List<StoryModel> {
        return  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val stories = storyApi.getStories()
            stories.body()?: emptyList()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you also providing StoryRepository & StoryService?

Comment: with the @Provides  annotation?

Comment: Yes. You have to provide these as well to Inject them

Comment: Also an advice, you can use Service or Repo (one of them). No need to add both.

Comment: This annotation is not applicable to target 'class' I get when I add the annotation

Comment: Not on class. Just like you are providing StoryApi & Retrofit in RetrofitStoryModule.
Are you also using a module in which you provide the Service, Repo and UseCase?

Answer (score 0):

adding the following code to your module:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideStoryService(@Named("StoryAPI") storyApi: StoryApi): 
 StoryService {
    return StoryService(storyApi)
}
```

And then change your GetStoryUseCase class to:

```
class GetStoryUseCase @Inject constructor(private val storyRepository: 
StoryRepository){
    suspend operator fun invoke(): List<StoryItem> {
        return storyRepository.getStories()
    }
}
```

to

```
class GetStoryUseCase @Inject constructor(private val storyService: 
StoryService){
    suspend operator fun invoke(): List<StoryItem> {
        return storyService.getStories().map {
            it.toStoryItem()
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!